# Runtime error 1004 "Method of Range Class Failed"

Tags: excel, vba, paste

I keep running into an error (which happens with no pattern or percieved reason).  The error occurs when I try to do a pastespecial (formulas or values).  I am curious if there is an alternative way to paste values or formulas in VBA given that the number of rows in the array is variable (1 to ~100).  I have attached the snippet of code below.

'both length and selectionarea are defined as strings

```
Range("P1").Select
```

'length is a formula in a cell that counts the length of the table

```
length = ActiveCell.Value
selectionarea = "B3:CM" + length
Range("B2:CM2").Select
Selection.Copy
Range(selectionarea).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
selectionarea = "C2:O" + length
Range(selectionarea).Select
Selection.Copy
Range("BL3").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
```

Comment: what is the value of `length` when you get the error? You should be using `&` to concatenate strings in VBA. `+` is not recommended. On what line does it fail?

Comment: When it fails (which is not every time), it fails on the pastespecial (either values or formulas).

Comment: and what is the vaule of `length` when it fails?

Comment: It also is doing the entire copy and paste within the same worksheet and workbook.  I will change the + length to & length...I do not think that is the cause of the error though.

Comment: The paste area must be compatible with the copyed area. That means, if you are copying from B2 to CM2, that's a single line. Then the paste area MUST have the same number of columns and as many lines as you like.

Comment: I have done that by specifying the equal number of columns, or the upperleft most corner of the paste location.  Will only specifying the corner create an occasional error?

Comment: the value of the length has been variable when it fails.  I have seen it be 6 and 49 in the last 2 days.  (probably a 1% failure rate).  Also - there are no merged cells which I know can create an occasional issue with pasting.

Comment: I think I am mistaken. You are indeed selecting the same number of columns. Use the length as integer, then concatenate the strings like this `"B3:CM" & trim(str(length))` - that will eliminate spaces that might occur.

Comment: There are no spaces.  The formulas in cell P1 that contains the length is =COUNTA(A:A)+1

Comment: I had an issue once, the spaces were created by the conversions of the value in the cell to string. I think it's worth a try. Maybe you're getting some range like `"B3:CM 49"`.

Comment: Tim fixed it all below.  thanks though

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this

```
Dim rng As Range, Length

Length = Range("P1").Value

'EDIT use this for formulas
Range("B2:E" & Length).Formula = Range("B2:E2").Formula
'or this should also work
'Range("B2:E" & Length).FillDown

Set rng = Range("C2:O" & Length)
Range("BL3").Resize(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count).Value = rng.Value
```

Comment: I have tried the formula above (I have not used code like this before...do not fully understand it).  For the formulas paste - it appears to have a problem with my application and am unsure how to fix it in the code.  The formula in B2 references BL2...when copied, the formula in B3 references BL3, B4 however references BL5, B5 is BL7, B6 is BL9.  B4 needs to reference BL4, B5 with BL5, and B6 with BL6.  Is there a way to address that in the code?

Comment: This code is very fast and useful I must say...is there an easy way to configure the code to copy values from one sheet to another?  Example Copying data from sheet1 to sheet2?

Comment: See my edit for formulas: my bad - I didn't test my original approach fully.  Copying between sheets should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Error: Method 'Paste' of object '_Worksheet' failed - 1004
Solution: Need to remeber the problems in Excel before copy the shapes from one sheet to another sheet.

1. Activate the Sheet(from where you are copying).
2. Select the Shapes from Sheet.
3. Copy the shapes from the Sheet.
4. Paste to shape to target sheet

Example: Previously my code is like below:

```
           Sheet1.Shapes(0).Copy
           Targetsheet.Paste
```

I have modified the like below:

```
           Sheet1.Activite
           Sheet1.Shapes(0).Select
           Sheet1.Shapes(0).Copy
           Targetsheet.Paste
```

Now it is working fine.